# How to create a path based on array with multiple children

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

So, basically what i'm trying to do is getting combinations of the array children, for example i got the array:

```php
[
"name" => "Item1", 
"children" => 
        [
        "name" => "Item2",
        "children" => [
                ["name" => "Item3"],
                ["name" => "Item4"]
                ]
        ],
        ["name" => "Item5"]
];
```

I tried to work with some functions i got on the stackoverflow, but i only got it to work with all of them at once, i was getting just

```php
[
"Item4" => "Item1/Item2/Item4",
"Item5" => "Item1/Item5"
];
```

The output should be

```php
[
"Item1" => "Item1",
"Item2" => "Item1/Item2",
"Item3" => "Item1/Item2/Item3"
"Item4" => "Item1/Item2/Item4"
"Item5" => "Item1/Item5"
];
```

As asked, the function i was working with before:

```php
function flatten($arr) {
    $lst = [];
    /* Iterate over each item at the current level */
    foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
        /* Get the "prefix" of the URL */
        $prefix = $item['slug'];
        /* Check if it has children */
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item) and sizeof($item['children'])) {
            /* Get the suffixes recursively */
            $suffixes = flatten($item['children']);
            /* Add it to the current prefix */
            foreach($suffixes as $suffix) {
                $url = $prefix . '/' . $suffix;
                $lst[$item['id']] = $url;
            }
        } else {
            /* If there are no children, just add the
             * current prefix to the list */
            $lst[$item['id']] = $prefix;
        }
    }

    return $lst;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to fix the data as the levels of data don't match up.  The rest of the code  is new as I found so many errors from your existing code.

Comments in code...

```
$data = [
    "name" => "Item1",
    "children" =>
    [[
        "name" => "Item2",
        "children" =>[
        ["name" => "Item3"],
        ["name" => "Item4"]]
    ],
    ["name" => "Item5"]]
];

print_r(flatten($data));

function flatten($arr, $pathSoFar = '') {
    $lst = [];
    $path = $pathSoFar."/";
    foreach ( $arr as $key => $value )  {
        if ( $key === 'name' )   {
            // Add name of current level onto path
            $path .= $value;
            $lst[$value] = $path;
        }
        else if ( $key === 'children' )  {
            //Process child elements recursively and add into current array
            $lst = array_merge($lst, flatten($value, $path));
        }
        else    {
            // This is for sub-elements which probably are (for example) 0, 1
            // (removing trailing / to stop multiples)
            $lst = array_merge($lst, flatten($value, rtrim($path,"/")));
        }
    }
    return $lst;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it working with your code, but i still dont understand why it returns each possibility instead of the sum of them

Comment: You can either step through the code or add in debugging data to show what it is working on.